# BMP File Format Confusion

Tags: c++, windows, bmp

I'm writing my own BMP file reader in C++, and there's some docs that i'm not so sure about.

In the Wiki page for the [BMP File Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format), there's a diagram of all the practical formats of BMP used out in the wild.

[image]

For the values that look like `8.8.8.0.8` like the 32 bpp `BI_RGB` in `BITMAPINFOHEADER`, does each value represent the amount of bits that can be used to represent each color channel in RGBAX? If this is the case, What is the 'X'? And why are there 8 bits devoted to it? Could i use this for an alpha channel?

Comment: Wikipedia is not the best place for such things.

Look at MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183391(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: BMP doesn't traditionally support alpha. So 0 bits are allocated for the A channel (alpha). In order to pad things to a nice 32-bit value, 8 bits are allocated to the X channel. Some programs will interpret the X channel as an alpha channel, but that's non-standard as far as I know.

Comment: @Cornstalks
I understand now, thank you!

Comment: There is nothing to be gained from writing something as complex as a bitmap reader. Someone already wrote one for you: [Windows Imaging Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The R.G.B.A.X notation used to be documented on Wikipedia (even with some colorful diagrams), but it has been deleted by some busybody there.  However, you can still find it in the history of the article, though.  See **[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=RGBA_color_space&oldid=398998394)**.

Anyway, `8.8.8.0.8` means that there are 32 bits per pixel (because the sum of all of the digits equals 32) and the `0` means, there are no bits for the Alpha channel (Alpha channel is not encoded in this format, nor in any of the palletized pixel formats).  The last `8` (at the fifth `X` position) means that there are 8 unused bits per pixel, in this encoding.

Also, the Wikipedia article and diagram below is more complete than anything the MSDN has on the subjet. See Chris Cox's criticism of the MSDN documentation **[here](https://forums.adobe.com/message/3272950#3272950)**:
[image]